NSF GRFP Field of Study different from department
Am I allowed to apply for NSF GRFP under Computer and Information Science and Engineering if I am in an applied math PhD program, but working with an advisor in the CS department?

From the administration guide (NSF 24-090): "Fellows must enroll in a graduate degree program consistent with the relevant field of study proposed in their application and undertake a course of study leading to a research-based master’s or doctoral degree."
Edit 2: Hopefully this addresses the critique in the comments.  As noted in the solicitation and administrative guide, the field on the application has to match the program the GRFP is studying.  As institutions vary considerably, one institution may have a degree program in Robotics, another may have one in Computer Science, but the time is spent studying robotics--that's what the research plan will show.  Either way, those degrees/programs roll up to CISE.
If the degree program you are pursuing is Applied Math, you cannot make the argument that you are in CISE--according to the Appendix, Applied Math belongs to Mathematical Sciences.  For example, if you are proposing that you are studying Artificial Intelligence despite pursuing a degree in Applied Math, how does it work?  Why are you not getting a degree in AI or Computer Science?  In this way, your subfield is Artificial Intelligence and not Applied Math, so why get a degree in Applied Math?
I work at an engineering school that does not have strict departments, so I understand how this path could happen, given the nature of collaborations between the fields.  However, the key is that the instructions say you "must enroll in a graduate degree program consistent with the relevant field of study".  So in this example, if your subfield is AI, they expect the degree program to also be focused on AI.  They would choose AI researchers to review your proposal.  If you choose Applied Math, the reviewers are from Applied Math.  It doesn't mean you can't have AI as a component in an Applied Math proposal, but the reviewers would be chosen differently.  If you felt that you could reasonably have AI as the subfield but have a degree in Applied Math, this would have to be explained and justified in your proposal.  I would also absolutely double-check with NSF prior to going this route.  Failure to do this properly could result in a return without review.
If you still have concerns, email NSF: info@nsfgrfp.org
Edited to add specific tie back to the solicitation:


Field of Study, Degree Programs, and Proposed Research

Fellowships are awarded for graduate study leading to research-based
Master's and doctoral degrees in science, technology, engineering or
mathematics (STEM) or in STEM education, in eligible Fields of Study
listed below:

Chemistry
Computer and Information Sciences and Engineering
Engineering
Geosciences
Life Sciences
Materials Research
Mathematical Sciences
Physics & Astronomy
Psychology
Social, Behavioral, and Economic Sciences
STEM Education and Learning Research

A complete list
of eligible Major Fields of Study and their subfields are listed in
the Appendix. If awarded, Fellows must enroll in a graduate degree
program consistent with the Major Field of Study proposed in their
application. A fellowship will not be awarded in a different Major
Field of Study from that indicated in the application.

Merit Review criteria in the solicitation:

Selection of a Major Field of Study determines the application
deadline, the broad disciplinary expertise of the reviewers, and the
discipline of the graduate degree program if awarded a Fellowship.
Applicants are advised to select the Major Field of Study in the GRFP
Application Module (see Fields of Study in Appendix) that is most
closely aligned with the proposed graduate program of study and
research plan. Applicants who select "Other" must provide additional
information describing their studies.

Appendix from the Solicitation:

X. Appendix NATIONAL SCIENCE FOUNDATION GRADUATE RESEARCH FELLOWSHIPS
Major Fields of Study
Note: Applications are reviewed based on the selection of a Major
Field of Study. As an example, CHEMISTRY is a Major Field of Study,
and Chemical Catalysis is a subfield under CHEMISTRY. A Fellowship can
be accepted only in the Major Field of Study indicated in the
application. Thus, an application that indicates CHEMISTRY as the
Major Field of Study can be accepted in any subfield in CHEMISTRY, but
cannot be accepted in CHEMICAL ENGINEERING, and ENGINEERING is a
different Major Field of Study.
Selection of a Major Field of Study determines the application
deadline, the broad disciplinary expertise of the reviewers who will
review the application, and the discipline of the graduate program if
the Fellowship is accepted. The subfield category designates specific
expertise of the reviewers. Applicants can select "Other" if their
specific subfield is not represented in the list of subfields under
the Major Field of Study. The "Other" subfield category should be
selected only if the proposed subfield is not covered by one of the
listed subfields, and should not be used to designate a subfield that
is more specific than the subfields listed.

You can see the Applied Math subfield is listed under Mathematical Sciences and not CISE.

COMPUTER AND INFORMATION SCIENCES & ENGINEERING

Accessibility
Algorithms and Theoretical Foundations
Artificial Intelligence
Augmented Reality/Virtual Reality, Graphics, and
Visualization
Bioinformatics and Bio-inspired Computing
Communication and Information Theory
Computationally Intensive Research
Computer Architecture
Computer Security and Privacy Computer Systems
Computer Vision
Cyber-Physical Systems and Embedded Systems
Cybersecurity
Data Science, Data Mining, Information Retrieval and Databases
Electronic Design Automation and Design of Micro and Nano Computing Systems
Fairness, Explainability, Accountability and Transparency in Analytics
Formal Methods, Verification, and Programming Languages
Human Computer Interaction
Information Sciences
Machine Learning
Natural Language Processing
Other (specify)
Parallel, Distributed, and Cloud Computing
Quantum Information Science
Robotics
Scientific Computing
Social Computing
Software Engineering
Wired and Wireless Networking


vs.

MATHEMATICAL SCIENCES

Algebra, Number Theory, and Combinatorics
Analysis
Applied Mathematics
Artificial Intelligence
Biostatistics
Computational and Data-enabled Science
Computational Mathematics
Computational Statistics
Computationally Intensive Research
Geometric Analysis
Logic or Foundations of Mathematics
Mathematical Biology
Other (specify)
Probability
Quantum Information
Science Statistics
Topology



Not sure that this quite answers the question as far as the OP's follow up would be "Is an applied math PhD program under supervision of a CS department advisor considered consistent with an application for a Computer and Information Science and Engineering GRFP?" which is pretty much what they already asked.

Having just gone through this with my student, I believe the intent by the NSF is to have students enroll in that degree program, so if they pick math, they need to be at a school with a math degree and enroll in that program. They also ask for subfield, but that's harder to check and enforce since that's driven by the research areas of faculty and students may not even start research in their first year anyway (NSF says students must be in the program of choice their first year).

@BryanKrause, as someone who administers payroll and appointments, including GRFPs, we have to use this guide as a starting point.  I don't find the instructions unclear.  There is an appendix in the solicitation with the fields and subfields.  The way the question is written, I can't tell if this person is meeting the required criteria.  What is the proposed field of study?  Applied Math?  That is listed in the appendix under "MATHEMATICAL SCIENCES" and not CISE, so in that case, the answer is no.  Applied Math PhD applies to "Mathematical Sciences".

@yourfriendlyresearchadmin What I imagine would be a helpful answer that is only possible from experience would be to address how the decision of what is "consistent" is made: does it primarily depend on the name/label of the program or degree? Or is it primarily based on the topic and framing of the research?

@yourfriendlyresearchadmin I would consider adding your comment (generalized) to the post, as it makes it more evident why it's so clear to you.

@BryanKrause, I may not be understanding what you mean by consistent.  I felt this was a rather black-and-white issue; can you tell me if my edit now addresses the part that may feel more "gray" to you?  I didn't mean to be unfriendly; it just feels very black and white on my side, so I didn't know what else could be addressed.

I think the edits are helpful; the possible confusion is that, although you say "applied math" is not listed, almost every field listed under CISE is an example of Applied Math, even though Applied Math is also in Mathematical Sciences. And most institutions are not going to have degrees in every one of these categories. If you are studying Computer Vision, you may very well be in an Applied Math degree program (also feasibly CS, even Psychology, etc).

So, the question is, if they read "Applied Math" do they also see "Ah, your Applied Math project is in Computer Vision so you would be eligible for either" or is it strictly "Applied Math is in this other list so that's where you belong".
